# How to train model on remote server?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0

We have a dgx server with 4 gpus, as it's storage capacity is less, we can't copy entire dataset there, so is there a way to send the data to DGX server in batches and train the model..?

We tried some options like `tf.config.experimental_connect_to_host(...)` but we were not successful..

I can answer any more questions if required.

Comment: You could use a network mount using `sshfs`. But given that datasets over network are massive bottlenecks, your efficiency may not be very good.

Comment: Yeah, as it’s for research it may not be optimal, but will look into it thank you.